# I want to know what is the best way to use Sonar?

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

1 - Is it just installing SonarLint on Eclipse and fixing errors reported by the plugin in real time?

2 -Or it's Installing a local version of Sonar Qube with the same rules and quality gates of the server and also Sonar Scanner, and before each commit run Sonar Scanner locally and check if Sonar will pass by success.

The first point is stressful because SonarLint plugin analyzes all the file and not just the last changes and it gives me many Sonar Warnings and Alerts that I don't need and it prevents me from moving forward in my  main task.

Comment: It's mainly opinion based, both tools you can use to produce a better code

Comment: it did not prevents, it saves your future time.

Comment: Yes, I know they are both correct, but I want to know the best way recommended by the community

Comment: Sonar Qube not only give you lints, it is also provide you major minor bugs, leaks, and code duplication,

Comment: My comment is we should fix lint error or time else it is tedious task for develoer to solve lint error.

Comment: @Himeshgoswami I agree with you and I understand what SonarQube can do (provide Bug, leaks, code duplication, coverage of unit tests...) 
But my question : I want to know the best practice used by the community or by the developpers. Because on the first point, I do the analysis only after the commit and if sonar falls in failure I have to recommit my correction (Of course I talk about the quality of code), while for the second point I can launch the local analysis is if it is KO I correct and relaunch and all that is locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install SonarLint in connected mode and connect it to your SonarQube instance. That way SonarLint will use quality profile setting from the SonarQube server. See more in the doc https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/#eclipse-connected-mode

Comment: I agree with you. If you read my comment above, I said that using this way is a little tiring as SonarLint analyzes the whole class and not just the modified code. But apparently SonarLint works this way.

Comment: This is the method I am currently using

Comment: @Mahmoud consider accepting the answer if you believe it's the right one